# Ubuntu 19.10 - unable to boot after crash during resizing partition, successfully recovered by Gparted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gparted

During a resize-move of the partition my machine hung - apparently only after copying the files - at the empty space level because this left my partition appear in Gparted with the used part, and a tiny slice of free space then the rest grayed out.

After booting on usb, I successfully had Gparted repair the partition who recovered the expected normal looks.

However, trying to boot it continuously fails (it's 19.10's partition on a multiboot system) as trying to use boot-repair resulted in the Ubuntu partition not to be recognized anymore.
Grub menu doesn't show my Ubuntu system and it is not listed when updating Grub.

When I mount the partition, the filesystem seems intact.

Also:

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda7
```

Did not seem to show any errors.

This is confirmed as:

```
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda7
```

Returned "nothing to do"

How can I boot successfully on my Ubuntu partition again under these circumstances?

Comment: Have you tried running update-grub on the damaged partition itself? In a multiple boot situation it can get confusing if there are multiple grub installs.  More detail about your system would be helpful.

Comment: I successfully ran grub-install on my /dev/sda7 partition but it is not recognized when I update grub "globally" and on sda7 but it doesn't recognize Ubuntu installed on /dev/sda7. It doesn't appear in the list of recognized OS's, and also running Boot-repair after that didn't help either.  What information on my system specifically would help? Please specify the commands output you need.

Comment: Did you run `update-grub` on `sda7`?

Comment: Absolutely, yes, I did.

Comment: The only other thing I can mention is that you need to run `update-grub` on whatever partition is the "primary" one with grub installed on it - the one that the PC actually boots with.  Since this gets so confusing, on my multiboot systems I've taken to removing grub from all one partition.  But when the other partitions get a new kernel, I have to come back to the primary one and run update-grub.

Comment: As mentionned, I did both. The Ubuntu system on the recovered partition /dev/sda7 is not recognized anymore.

Comment: OK, I'm out of ideas. Best wishes!

Comment: It seems that my computer froze while displacing the partition so it was not recoverable despite all attempts, I had to reinstall 19.10. (the partition I resized). Originally I thought there was a chance that my computer froze after displacing the data, in the free space section, but no.